# Search Table using Data Tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I get the search working on my tables using Data Tables:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        var catalogueSearch;
        var noResultsFound = false;
        var oldSearch = 0;

        var selectedContractsTable = $('.catalogueLinkedContractsTable').DataTable({
            "sDom": 't<"dt-panelfooter clearfix"ip>',
            "bSort": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bSearch": true,
            "paging": false,
            "searching": true,
            "order": [[2, "asc"]],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No linked contracts found.",
                "zeroRecords": "No linked contracts found.",
                "info": "_START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_"
                },
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": [2],
                    "sClass": "hidden-xs hidden-sm"
                },
                {
                    "targets": [3,4],
                    "sClass": "hidden-xs",
                },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "targets": [5],
                    "sClass": "updateTableRow text-center",
                    "defaultContent": "<button class=\"btn btn-danger br2 btn-xs fs12 table-btn\" id=\"AddContractBtn\">Remove</button>"
                }
            ]
        });

        var contractsTable = $('.catalogueContractsTable').DataTable({
            "sDom": 't<"dt-panelfooter clearfix"ip>',
            "bSort": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bSearch": true,
            "paging": false,
            "searching": true,
            "order": [[2, "asc"]],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No contracts found.",
                "zeroRecords": "No contracts found.",
                "info": "_START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": [2],
                    "sClass": "hidden-xs hidden-sm"
                },
                {
                    "targets": [3,4],
                    "sClass": "hidden-xs"
                },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "targets": [5],
                    "sClass": "updateTableRow text-center",
                    "defaultContent": "<button class=\"btn btn-success br2 btn-xs fs12 table-btn\" id=\"AddContractBtn\">Add</button>"
                }
            ]

        });
```

**Table Search**

```
@* Table Search *@

        $('#tableSearch').on('keyup', function () {
            table.search(this.value).draw();
        });
```

For some reason, I cant get the search to work on my table. There are no errors in the console. I have tried a number of examples on the site but I can not seem to get them working. Would anyone have any ideas, please? Is there more to it than the examples? I am sure its a simple issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.catalogueContractsTable').DataTable();

            $('input#tableSearch').on('keyup', function () {
                $('.catalogueContractsTable')
                    .DataTable()
                    .search($('input#tableSearch').val(), false, true)
                    .draw();
            });
        });

        @* Table Search for Unlinked Contracts *@
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.catalogueLinkedContractsTable').DataTable();

            $('input#tableSearch').on('keyup', function () {
                $('.catalogueLinkedContractsTable')
                    .DataTable()
                    .search($('input#tableSearch').val(), false, true)
                    .draw();
            });
        });
```

It now works with any column present in the table.